# Docker fails on changed GCP virtual machine?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a problem with Docker that seems to happen when I change the machine type of a Google Compute Platform VM instance. Images that were fine fail to run, fail to delete, and fail to pull, all with various obscure messages about missing keys (this on Linux), duplicate or missing layers, and others I don't recall.

The errors don't always happen. One that occurred just now, with an image that ran a couple hundred times yesterday on the same setup, though before a restart, was:

```
$ docker run --rm -it mbloore/model:conda4.3.1-aq0.1.9
docker: Error response from daemon: layer does not exist.
$ docker pull mbloore/model:conda4.3.1-aq0.1.9
conda4.3.1-aq0.1.9: Pulling from mbloore/model
Digest: sha256:4d203b18fd57f9d867086cc0c97476750b42a86f32d8a9f55976afa59e699b28
Status: Image is up to date for mbloore/model:conda4.3.1-aq0.1.9
$ docker rmi mbloore/model:conda4.3.1-aq0.1.9
Error response from daemon: unrecognized image ID sha256:8315bb7add4fea22d760097bc377dbc6d9f5572bd71e98911e8080924724554e
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
$
```

So it thinks it has no images, but the Docker folders are full of files, and it does know some hashes. It looks like some index has been damaged.
I restarted that instance, and then Docker seemed to be normal again without any special action on my part.

The only workarounds I have found so far are to restart and hope, or to delete several large Docker directories, and recreate them empty. Then after a restart and pull and run works again. But I'm now not sure that it always will.

I am running with Docker version 17.05.0-ce on Debian 9. My images were built with Docker version 17.03.2-ce on Amazon Linux, and are based on the official Ubuntu image.

Has anyone had this kind of problem, or know a way to reset the state of Docker without deleting almost everything?

Comment: Hi, which is the operating system and the Docker version you are using? Are you able to reproduce this issue? Can you provide the steps?

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

1) It seems that changing the VM had nothing to do with it. On some boots Docker worked, on others not, with no change in configuration or contents.

2) At Google's suggestion I installed Stackdriver monitoring and logging agents, and I haven't had a problem through seven restarts so far.

My first guess is that there is a race condition on startup, and adding those agents altered it in my favour. Of course, I'd like to have a real fix, but for now I don't have the time to pursue the problem.